# Open previous viewed tab in Chrome shortcut

Tags: google-chrome

I have opened many tabs in mu Chrome. Is it possible somehow open previously viewed tab using keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+SHIFT+T opens the last *closed* tab, and it can be repeated.

If you mean tabbing through the *open* Tabs, you can do that with CTRL+TAB, and you can address a specific tab with CTRL+n where N is a digit between 1 and 9 (for the first 9 tabs)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean MRU tab switching , you need an extension for that.

https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/af0CrX_48pk/pu2W0c6O5xUJ